# unable to run rake db:migrate with docker compose

Tags: docker-compose, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new to docker and was trying to follow this tutorial [learn docker](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2018/01/02/dockerizing-a-rails-app)

I am getting following error while trying to run

```
docker-compose run web rake db:create
```

I tried removing entrypoint of DockerFile but it is the same results. Could anyone point me what I am doing wrong ?

```
    /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/base.rb:507:in `handle_argument_error': ERROR: "rails server" was called with arguments ["db:create"] (Thor::InvocationError)
Usage: "rails server [puma, thin etc] [options]"
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:34:in `rescue in run'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:21:in `run'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from /myapp/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /myapp/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /myapp/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    from /myapp/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never. After cloning the git repo you want to replace the Dockerfile with the Dockerfile from the tutorial page [learn docker](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2018/01/02/dockerizing-a-rails-app)

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue, I updated my docker file and replaced `ENTRYPOINT` statement with `CMD` and sample docker file I used to setup my rails application is mentioned below:

```yaml
FROM ruby:3.1.1-slim

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install ruby-full build-essential -y && \
  apt-get install libpq-dev -y

COPY . .

RUN gem install bundler:2.3

RUN gem update --system

RUN bundle install

RUN if [ -f tmp/pids/server.pid ]; then rm tmp/pids/server.pid; fi 

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

After that I created this docker compose:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    build: .
    restart: always
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ".:/usr/src/app"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  
  postgres:
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "data:/data/db"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password

volumes:
  data:
```

and after `docker compose up`

Running:

```
docker compose run api bin/rails db:create
```

worked for me.